# hostname -d in PHP

Tags: php, linux, sockets, dns, websocket

There is the PHP function `gethostname()` and `php_uname('n')`, but both return only the hostname, but not the domainname returned by the command `hostname -d`.

Is there a native way, that maybe also works on windows, without executing a new process, to get this information?

Comment: only works on linux that I'm aware of, but:

   rickbuford@ent01:~$ domainname
   (none)

Answer (score 0):

In my tests the following printed the FQDN of my host:

```
echo gethostbyaddr(gethostbynamel(gethostname())[0]);
```

I'm not sure, which local DNS configuration is needed to reliably get the FQDN by this command sequence. However, you can give it a try...

Comment: As you say it depends on the local dns configuration. So it is not optimal. :/